# Prefab not working when I import maps form Tiled using Tiled2Unity

Tags: unity, tiled, prefabs, tiled2unity

I have correctly created the map using Tiled with no errors or warnings, then i imported the package from tiled2unity, imported the map then waited few seconds and the prefab from tiled2unity appears only after some minutes but not working.

the tiled to unity package imported
[image: The map]

The error[image: ][2]]

the map
[image: The map]

Basically i dont see the tiled map in unity after it's imported.

Comment: What specific symptoms of "not working" do you observe?

Comment: It is able to get in the project but i can t see the sprite of the map

Comment: I notice you have an error in your console log. Anything interesting there? You may also want to show us what the map is supposed to look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error message, it looks like Tiled2Unity is trying to do something illegal in this version of Unity, and so its operation is aborted.

The website for the tool reads:

> **Warning: Tiled2Unity is old software!**
> Tiled2Unity was created before Unity had support for tiles and tilemaps. It is still available for download but is outdated and unsupported. Consider using [SuperTiled2Unity](https://seanba.com/supertiled2unity.html) instead. Thanks!

And the SuperTiled2Unity page elaborates:

> SuperTiled2Unity is the second generation of Tiled2Unity, a popular exporter I first released in May of 2014 which is now deprecated.

This means the original version of the tool is no longer supported, and may not perform as desired on more recent Unity versions. I'd recommend using the updated version instead.

Comment: Thank you, it worked with supertiled2unity